# Generate cells for CSS grid via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm

I'm trying to generate grid cells dynamically, but in a specific pattern.
I copied a lot of `<div>`s, made the necessary adjustments by hand, and got the results I needed, but I'm wondering if someone can help me in developing an algorithm for producing it automatically. If you look at the example below, the left box is what I want to dynamically calculate.

```js
function calcCells(){
let cells = '';
  for(let a = 1; a <= 10; a++){
    for(let b = 1; b <= a; b++){
        cells += `<div style="background:#fd8362; grid-area: ${a % b} / ${a % b} / ${a % b} / ${a % b}">
        ${b}
      </div>`
    }
  }
  return cells;
}

document.getElementById("grid-body-algorithm").innerHTML = calcCells();
```

```css
#grid-body,
#grid-body-algorithm {
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: end;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    color:#444444;
    padding:1px;
}

#grid-body > *,
#grid-body-algorithm > *{
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-body">
  <div style="background:#fd8362; grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1">1</div>

  <div style="background:#ffad97; grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 1">1</div>
  <div style="background:#ffad97; grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2">2</div>

  <div style="background:#ffded6; grid-area: 3 / 1 / 3 / 1">1</div>
  <div style="background:#ffded6; grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2">2</div>
  <div style="background:#ffded6; grid-area: 1 / 3 / 1 / 3">3</div>

  <div style="background:#fff0ec; grid-area: 4 / 1 / 4 / 1">1</div>
  <div style="background:#fff0ec; grid-area: 3 / 2 / 3 / 2">2</div>
  <div style="background:#fff0ec; grid-area: 2 / 3 / 2 / 3">3</div>
  <div style="background:#fff0ec; grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 4">4</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-body-algorithm">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the desired output, we can see that the [taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from the top-left corner determines the desired color, and the column number determines the cell text.

The inner loop should be constrained to stay within a maximum taxicab distance. This maximum could be a parameter to your function. In your example that maximum is 3 (as the furthest cells that are concerned are 3 taxicab steps away from the top-left cell).

Furthermore, the desired color seems to get lighter the greater that taxicab distance is. For that we could vary the [alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model) part of the same, fixed background color. In RGBA notation, this alpha component which can have a value between 0 and 1.

I opted for creating a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead of HTML. That way the setting of cell attributes is more JS-syntax controlled and more object oriented.

I didn't touch your CSS.

In this implementation I added an input box with which you can control the maximum taxicab distance that will be used:

```js
function calcCells(maxDistance) {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    // row + col - 2 is taxicab distance from top-left corner
    for (let col = 1, distance = row - 1; distance <= maxDistance && col <= 5; col++, distance++) { 
        const cell = document.createElement("div");
        // Set background transparency with the alpha part of the background color
        cell.style.background = `rgba(240,120,80,${1 - (distance + 0.5) / (maxDistance + 1)})`;
        cell.style.gridArea = [row, col, row, col].join(" / ");
        cell.textContent = col;
        fragment.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
  return fragment;
}

const inputDistance = document.querySelector("input");
const outputGrid = document.getElementById("grid-body-algorithm");

function refresh() {
    const maxDistance = +inputDistance.value;
    outputGrid.innerHTML = ""; // clear previous content
    outputGrid.appendChild(calcCells(maxDistance));
}

inputDistance.addEventListener("click", refresh);
refresh();
```

```css
#grid-body,
#grid-body-algorithm {
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: end;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    color:#444444;
    padding:1px;
}

#grid-body > *,
#grid-body-algorithm > *{
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-body-algorithm"></div>
distance: <input type="number" value="3" min="0" max="8">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use an `eventListener` or the `defer`-attribute to wait until the DOM structure is loaded and the element exists.

Then you should not use `innerHTML` to create elements. It is slow as the DOM needs to be reparsed and is an XSS-Injection vulnerability.

To create Elements use either the `appendChild` or the `insertAdjacentHTML` method.

Instead of adding everything as `inline-style` I would work with CSS which is cleaner and with the use of SASS even shorter.

As you already figured out, you need 2 variables. One for the row and one for the column. The first `for`-loop needs the one for the rows and the 2nd for the columns:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  for (let i = 1, n = 5; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      document.querySelector('#grid-body-algorithm').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <div data-row="${i}" data-col="${j}">${j}</div>`
      );
    }
    n--;
  }
})
```

```css
#grid-body-algorithm {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  padding: 2px;
  gap: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

[data-row="1"] { grid-row: 1 / 2; }
[data-row="2"] { grid-row: 2 / 3; }
[data-row="3"] { grid-row: 3 / 4; }
[data-row="4"] { grid-row: 4 / 5; }
[data-row="5"] { grid-row: 5 / 6; }

[data-row="1"][data-col="1"] { background: #fd8362; }
[data-row="1"][data-col="2"],
[data-row="2"][data-col="1"] { background: #ffad97; }
[data-row="1"][data-col="3"],
[data-row="2"][data-col="2"],
[data-row="3"][data-col="1"] { background: #ffded6; }
[data-row="1"][data-col="4"],
[data-row="2"][data-col="3"],
[data-row="3"][data-col="2"],
[data-row="4"][data-col="1"] { background: #fff0ec; }
```

```html
<div id="grid-body-algorithm"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really appreciate it. It can be really useful for other circumstances.